# Mobile Firefox browser does not show shortcut icon on home screen

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, meta-tags, favicon

The issue which I faced is specific and related only to the `Android` mobile `Firefox` browser (in my case version `113.2.0`). I'm not sure if the system matters, but it is `OxygenOS` version `11.1.2.2`.

Basically I set `favicon/shortcut-icon` as shown in many examples. I have tried many of them and the `favicon` works in desktop and mobile browsers, except the mentioned `Firefox`.. For the mobile `Firefox` browser, I just have a random coloured icon with the first letter of the domain in the middle of the shortcut..

I even tried code as large as the one below:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="194x194" href="/favicon/android-icon-194x194.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

As you can see, `Firefox` does not use the `apple-touch-icon` tag, `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` tag, or the `icon` tag, even if it is `192x192` or `194x194`. It also doesn't work with the default `favicon.ico` icon placed in `main/root` folder..

The result is always the same... A random coloured background icon with the first letter of the domain inside. The result I want to achieve is my custom home screen icon and the shortcut should open the page in the browser (non-native full-screen mode which can be achieved by setting additional meta tags)..

Comment: Same problem here, tried everything but still no icon